# Circular UIScrollView – SwiftCarousel: Want to autoscroll

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, infinite-scroll, pager, autoscroll

I am using a third party for circular scrollview and Everything is perfect. Only thing that i want is scrollview should autoscroll so that images should be autoscroll after every 15 second. Third Party Link:  https://github.com/DroidsOnRoids/SwiftCarousel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: I want to ask in Example 2 is there any way images should be autoscroll after every 15 second?

A:
Hey!

There is no built-in method that we've made, but you can use NSTimer that will do a task every 15 second, and the task would select the next item using method selectItem(:animated). You should be also aware that you might try to select to the index that is lower than 0 or index that is higher than the amount of items in carousel, so you have to be sure to make the conditional statements.

Cheers!

i found above in SwiftCarousel homepage (http://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/ios/circular-scroll-view-swiftcarousel/).

Edit:

```
//declaring variables
var carouselTimer : NSTimer!
var counter = 0
//

//in viewDidLoad
carouselTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: #selector(selectIteminCarousel), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
//

func selectIteminCarousel()
{
    carousel.selectItem(counter, animated: true)
    counter += 1
    if counter > 2
    {
        self.counter = 0
    }

}
```

this piece of code makes carousel autoscroll.